# Should I mix use printf with std::cin?

Tags: c++, c, printf

Update2: the buffer is what I was looking for in the second question. Thanks.

---

Update: Thanks for the answers. I will do more research and practice on i/o streams.

Another question if you don't mind:

I have some background in chemical engineering and we often have to deal with accumulation over time between i/o streams.

This might be a strange question considering digital signals are more or less perfect (?) compared to physical material streams. But practically speaking, are there any scenarios something like that might happen?

Perhaps a relevant area would be network security?

---

I'm trying to practice C++ along side C, and I know that C++ is a lot more versatile and safer when it comes down to certain things like the std i/o.

However, it's incredibly frustrating trying to break a sentence into small chunks using `std::cout`. The work grows exponentially tedious when you have a long string you have to type. This is simply way too counter intuitive compared to the simpler printf.

For example:

```
// The same line of code with printf()
     printf("#%2d", i);

// Compared to C++ where I have to include the formatting library.
```

My question is, is it safe to use `printf` strictly for output and `std::cin` for input if safety is the whole point of the iostream library?

Comment: Safety is not the only reason of `<iostream>`. It offers much more than that.

Comment: Completely agree, but a better solution than printf would be to use the boost format library, https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/format/doc/format.html

Comment: `cin` seems to be irrelevant. It sounds like your question is just whether it's OK to use `printf()` in a C++ program.

Comment: Yes, you can mix `std::cin` with `printf`, one being for input, the other one for output they are pretty unrelated.. But mixing `std:cout` with `printf` might be a bad idea.

Comment: I don't know enough about the deep under the hood stuff. My frustration is from the tedious work with std::cout mostly. I only know from a very cursory level that upstream is supposedly safe. Safer how, I have no idea.

Comment: What you're asking is mostly opinion-based. There is some interaction between C++ streams and C library's stdio, that can come into play in certain edge cases, but that's very rare. But, more importantly, you should try to make your best effort to buckle up an deal with streams. If you think streams are difficult, you ain't seen nothing yet. C++ is the most complicated general purpose programming language in use today, and there are far more convoluted parts to C++, by orders of magnitude, than streams.

Comment: If I have do it, I will do it. Can you give me a few pointers to where I should read to understand more about streams in Cpp?

Comment: C++20 introduced string formating. Use cout << format(fmtstring, args, ...) with {} format specifiers in python style

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your 'Update' appears to be a separate, though related question. You may want to clarify what you're asking & integrate it more with your original question. Otherwise, you should probably post it as a separate question altogether.

Comment: What is accumulation over time between I/O streams?

Comment: Let's say you have a stream of crude oil flowing in at constant rate into a refinery tower on one side, and the other side you have an extraction stream of the refined product. Over time there will be accumulation in the tower -- heavy substance sinking to the bottom is one example. So occasionally you have to flush out through a separate stream. There is also the the case of recycle stream but I'd rather not get too deeply into that.

Comment: In general, it's advisable not to mix both C and C++, they are wildly different languages although they can cooperate quite well. But even then, there are often some quirks about it which can be a difficult to detect source of errors. So decide whether you want to use C or C++. There are reasons for and against for both, but most people (including me) have a strong preference for one of them. Just, don't mix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So your question is: Is it safe to mix the use of printf with cin?

The answer is yes! Yes we can, you can use C functions and libraries in C++, although the C++ ones are much more safer and should be more optimized, yet sometimes printf is much more faster than cin, but it depends on what you're trying to print. printf has to parse the string you've entered while cin has to perform some complex stuff too. Also as pointed out by @Sebastian, the speed will vary upon how much you flush the input buffer.

Suppose I want to print the string "Hello, World" 10,000 times without any new line, by using printf and std::cout, by trying this on my machine I got the following result:

printf took 11619360 [µs] -> 11.61936 [s]

cout took 3243804 [µs] -> 3.243804 [s]

Below is the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point time1 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    for(unsigned int i=0;i<10000;i++)
    {
        printf("Hello, World");
        //std::cout << "Hello, World";
    }
    std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point time2 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

    std::cout << "Duration " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(time2 - time1).count() << " [µs]" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Here std::cout was faster than printf, but it all depends on what you're trying to print

Comment: The speed could also depend on how often the functions flush the output

Comment: That's write too @Sebastian

Comment: Decoupling C++ streams (std::cin, std::cout) and C I/O buffers (stdin, stdout) can improve the performance, but then only one or the other should be used, because they no longer play nice together.

Comment: It is worth mentioning that iostream buffers (cout, cin, &c) really aren't safe to mix with printf & readline in multithreaded / concurrent programming environments. Outside that, however, this answer is pretty much spot on.